# soundcloud: /oauth2/token {"error":"invalid_grant"}

Tags: curl, token, soundcloud

i've just received my soundcloud API client_id, client_secret and auth. code and tried multiple 'curl' like clients for windows/linux even "hurl.it" to receive a token like the example at the API page shows.

```
curl -X POST "https://api.soundcloud.com/oauth2/token" -F 'client_id=XXXXX' -F 'client_secret=XXXXX' -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' -F 'redirect_uri=SOME_ADDRESS' -F 'code=XXXXX'
```

response from all is `{"error":"invalid_grant"}`

"redirect_uri: The redirect uri you have configured for your application"

^ i don't have an actual redirect_uri for now so SOME_ADDRESS is some random value, but i don't think that matters.

i've checked multiple times and client_id, client_secret and auth. code are correct.
any idea why the error occurs?

Comment: _“i don't have an actual redirect_uri for now so SOME_ADDRESS is some random value, but i don't think that matters”_ – usually with OAuth2 it _does_ matter, because apps are normally tied to specified domains.

Comment: any notes on how to create a valid redirect_uri?
i just wanted to create a simple/test application that loads audio streams from soundcloud. it does not have a website.

Comment: @lobolmart If you do not require any fancy validation on the server side, then there are some pages which are just there to be redirect too like http://example.com/callback. Else use your own redirect server and handle the callback yourself.